# Java Class will not import to .jsp file

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, tomcat, import

I am trying to use a java class I created named ParseForm, with a jsp file I created, but when I import it with `<%@ page import="myPackage.ParseForm" %>`, eclipse underlines it in red and gives the message "The import myPackage cannot be resolved".

The name of my project is ARForm, and the path of the ParseForm class is /ARForm/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/classes/myPackage/ParseForm.java. I am using tomcat v8 to run on server in eclipse. Everything was running smoothly and I am able to import standard java classes such as java.io, except now that I try to import my own class it will not compile.

I have read a bunch of forums and everyone on the website with the same problem as me was able to fix it by moving there class into WEB-INF and/or creating a package, but when I did these things I continue to get the same error.

Please let me know if I am omitting any important information that would help solve this problem; this is my first experience with jsp and web development, my only prior experience is that I took AP computer science at my high school last year. Thank you in advance!

Here is the error stacktrace:

```
Stacktrace:
org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.javacError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:102)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.javacError(ErrorDispatcher.java:198)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler.generateClass(JDTCompiler.java:457)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:361)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:336)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:323)
org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:585)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:363)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:396)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:340)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse give you error because it couldn't found the class you are importing. In a Maven webapp project the structure is as follow:

```
ARForm
|-- src
    |-- main
        |-- java
            |-- myPackage
                |-- ParseForm.java
        |-- resources
        |-- webapp
            |-- WEB-INF
                |-- web.xml
            |-- index.jsp
```

All your Java codes should be placed under the java folder. To run from Eclipse you need to setup Tomcat in your Eclipse Servers tab. Then you can run your project by right click Run As -> Run on Server

Comment: so I made that change and it no longer underlines it in red but gives error 500 when I submit the form saying that it can't import because myPackage.ParseForm is a package, not an object. I figured maybe rebuilding it would fix it but running "Maven Build..." with goal "clean verify" said that it couldn't build because it couldn't find web.xml, even though web.xml shows in eclipse. After failing to rebuild, it can't run in tomcat either :(

Comment: Update: so I looked a little bit closer at my pom.xml and it says that ARForm/target/m2e-wtp/web-resources/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF it isn't able to find / doesn't exist

Comment: So apparently the problem was that my webapp folder was in src, rather than main. Now I am able to build with maven but i still get error 500 after sending the form when running on tomcat.

Comment: The scr/main/java etc is how maven structure our project directory. The root for java source should be java directory while webapp in the root of the web application.

Comment: @DaneWilliams did you manage to display the jsp with the import statement?

Comment: No, the import statement is no longer underlined in red, but when I run it, the form for the first jsp shows up, then I click send, which is supposed to redirect me to my next jsp where I import myPackage.ParseForm, but instead gives "HTTP Status 500 - Unable to compile class for JSP:"